# Google sign in with Firebase in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I trying login with google_sign_in with firebase , but when choose gmail account then Exception, please help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52uKx.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70Esf.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the sign-in with google in firebase and restarted the application.